# Fullcalendar joomla 3.7.2 select callback not triggering

Tags: fullcalendar

I have fullcalendar on Joomla 3.72. site along with bootstrap. 
The select event is not triggering
MY configuration is v1.12.4, bootstrap 3.2 and moment 2.18.1
You can see it here http://pedy.dextera.gr/index.php?option=com_elgpedy&view=personelscommittees&layout=personelscommittees&Itemid=118

by using the following credentials
user: test
password: 1234

Bellow is my code:

```
jQuery('#personelsComittees').fullCalendar({


    locale: 'el',
    selectable: true,
    editable: true,
    eventStartEditable : false,
    selectHelper: true,
    allDayDefault: true,
    eventLimit: false,

    select: function(start, end) {
        elgInitCommitteeModal();
        jQuery('#StartDateCommittee').val(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD' ));
        jQuery('#EndDateCommittee').val(end.subtract(1, 'seconds').format('YYYY-MM-DD' ));
        jQuery('#PersonelScheduleId').val('');                        
        jQuery('#personelsCommitteesForm').modal({});

    },      

    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        elgInitCommitteeModal();
        if(calEvent.end === null ) calEvent.end = calEvent.start;
        jQuery('#StartDateCommittee').val(calEvent.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        jQuery('#EndDateCommittee').val( calEvent.end.format('YYYY-MM-DD') );                    
        jQuery('#PersonelScheduleId').val(calEvent.PersonelScheduleId);
        if(calEvent.PersonelScheduleId != '') {
            elgCEFD[calEvent.PersonelScheduleId] = calEvent._id;
        }
        jQuery('#HealthCommitteeId').val(calEvent.HealthCommitteeId);                                                    
        jQuery('#PersonelId').val(calEvent.PersonelId);                        
        jQuery('#delTitle').text(calEvent.title);
        jQuery('#delDates').text(calEvent.start.format('dddd DD/M/YYYY') + ' - ' + calEvent.end.format('dddd DD/M/YYYY'));                                        
        jQuery('#committeAskDel').show();
        jQuery('#personelsCommitteesForm').modal({});
    },
    now:  [jQuery('#RefYear').val(), jQuery('#RefMonth').val() -1, 1], 
    events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?option=com_elgpedy&view=' + elgview + '&format=json&Itemid=' + elgItemid,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                HealthUnitId :  document.getElementById('HealthUnitId').value,
                start:  start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                end: end.subtract(1, 'seconds').format('YYYY-MM-DD')  
            },
            success: function(response) {
                showDataArea();
                callback(response);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

thanks in advance

Comment: well firstly since you are using fullCalendar 3.4, you require jQuery 2.0 or above and momentJS 2.9 or above. See https://fullcalendar.io/support/. Fix that any any other compatibility issues, and then see if you still have the same problem

Comment: I have downgrade the fullcallendar to v1 and still is the same. While event "click" triggers the "select" event is not triggering.I am using  jQuery 1.12.4, fullcalendar 2.2.1, moment 2.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was a problem with jQuery versions, as ADyson mentioned. Unfortunelly by downgrading fullcallendar did not solve my problem, because calendar needed and older jQuery version from joomla's current version.

So I make a copy of my template and I customize it so as it loads JQuery version I needed. I guess I was lucky cause no conflict rised up with other modules.